# Pure-ftpd with MySQL - Crypt() not logging me in with hashed passwords

Tags: mysql, ftp, authentication, encryption, pureftpd

I am using pure-ftpd with mysql to auth users.

Here is my mysql.conf

```
MYSQLServer     localhost
MYSQLPort       3306
MYSQLSocket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
MYSQLUser       user
MYSQLPassword   pwd
MYSQLDatabase   my_db
MYSQLCrypt      crypt()
MYSQLGetPW      SELECT password FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MYSQLGetUID     SELECT u_id FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MYSQLGetGID     SELECT g_id FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MYSQLGetDir     SELECT dir FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetQTAFS   SELECT quota_files FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetQTASZ  SELECT quota_size FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetRatioUL SELECT ul_ratio FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetRatioDL SELECT dl_ratio FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetBandwidthUL SELECT ul_bandwidth FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
MySQLGetBandwidthDL SELECT dl_bandwidth FROM ftp_users WHERE login="\L"
```

I then have tried restarting pure-ftpd-mysql and pure-ftpd

My table has a field with the pwd as

```
password    varchar(255)
```

When I insert a user with a plaintext pwd, I can login fine with both login and password.  When I insert a hash with 'lol' such as SHA512 or a BCrypt hash.  It doesn't allow me to login with the pwd 'lol'.

```
BCrypt $2a$06$JrvxpMAvi6MnRSIvZQMMxOffIDLtEP7lrKNe0k0CTsK51v4zujfpS
SHA512 3DD28C5A23F780659D83DD99981E2DCB82BD4C4BDC8D97A7DA50AE84C7A7229A6DC0AE8AE4748640A4CC07CCC2D55DBDC023A99B3EF72BC6CE49E30B84253DAE
```

However, if I paste in the hash, it successfully logs in as I assume it takes it as a  plaintext value.

I have tried changing the mysql.conf to

```
MYSQLCrypt      crypt
```

But this breaks it completely.  There are many sites which say to use crypt,  but the comments in my configuration file list crypt() as one of the options.

I have read through many posts and forums but the closest thing I found was this, which doesn't work at all.

https://serverfault.com/a/630806/302696

Here is what pure-ftpd starts with

```
Starting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-mysql -l mysql:/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb -E -F /etc/pure-ftpd/fortunes.txt -j -H -J ALL:!aNULL:!SSLv3 -u 1000 -8 UTF-8 -A -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -B
```

So basically it is not using crypt or I am not using it correctly.  I though it could handle SHA512 natively with mysql but it doesn't.  Other things I can think of is that I need code with the configuration but I can't see why it would require anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**--- BEGIN tl;dr ---**

Assuming your Pure-FTPd is running on a Linux host with glibc 2.7+:

- Use `MySQLCrypt crypt` – **without** parentheses
- Run this Python 3 one-liner on the same system where Pure-FTPd runs:

  ```
  python3 -c 'import sys, crypt, getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass("Password: "), crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'
  ```
- Enter the desired password.
- Copy and paste the crypt-ed password (starting with `$6$`) into the database.

**--- END tl;dr ---**

The idea behind non-plaintext `MySQLCrypt` is to disable plaintext passwords altogether.  The parenthesized `MySQLCrypt crypt()` still accepting the hash as a plaintext password suggests that Pure-FTPd treated the string `crypt()` as an unknown crypt method and ignored the directive altogether, using the default crypt method of plaintext instead.  The un-parenthesized `MySQLCrypt crypt` “breaking” plaintext logins is actually a step in the right direction: It disabled plaintext login and started treating passwords in the database as crypt-ed only.

Now, the question is how to properly hash a password into an acceptable form.  According to `src/mysql.c` of Pure-FTPd, `MySQLCrypt crypt` would cause it to use the `crypt()` function, whose acceptable forms [depend on the implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Support_in_operating_systems).  For example, if you are running Pure-FTPd on a Linux machine with glibc 2.7 or higher, there are 4 forms accepted:

- SHA-512 (starts with `$6$`)
- SHA-256 (starts with `$5$`)
- MD5 (starts with `$1$`)
- Traditional DES (starts with an alphanumeric letter); should probably be avoided though

There are a few ways of invoking the system `crypt()`; my preferred method is Python 3's built-in [`crypt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) module.  This short script would do our bidding:

```
import sys
from crypt import crypt, METHOD_SHA512
from getpass import getpass

print(crypt(getpass("Password: "), METHOD_SHA512))
```

Or if you prefer a triple-clickable, copy-and-paste-friendly one-liner:

```
python3 -c 'import sys, crypt, getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass("Password: "), crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'
```

A sample run:

```
root@ip-172-16-16-117:~# python3 -c 'import sys, crypt, getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass("Password: "), crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'
Password: 
$6$vTbR62VMHKQNqnEk$TmfeMj/Q6G62RM.hi7liD0IrEvtUp2.jgXbfVRPone/sFTeOwJKftTrrW9j8Hd8.kJsF36OKwP4xHrnURGZTo/
```

It is imperative that this command be run on the same host where Pure-FTPd runs, in order to use the same `crypt()` implementation.

The long line that starts with `$6$` is the crypt-ed password.  The `$6$` prefix itself marks the password as hashed using SHA-512.  If the system `crypt()` does not support SHA-512, the output will not start `$6$`; in this case, another algorithm should be used.  For example, on macOS, a possible output is `$6UCLzI8sPv16`.  Note that it is excessively short and also lacks the dollar sign after `$6`: This is because the macOS implementation of `crypt()` does not support SHA-512.

Comment: By the way, the `SHA512 3DD28C5A23F780659D83DD99981E2DCB82BD4C4BDC8D97A7DA50AE84C7A7229A6DC0AE8AE4748640A4CC07CCC2D55DBDC023A99B3EF72BC6CE49E30B84253DAE` hash you posted is the **unsalted** hash of the password string (`lol`).  Pure-FTPd supports only two unsalted password hashes: SHA-1 (`MySQLCrypt sha1`) and MD5 (`MySQLCrypt md5`), and [even those two are deprecated](https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.MySQL).  Unsalted SHA-512 is unsupported, and will likely be never implemented.

Comment: Thank-you for explaining this step by step, I was seriously at loss with why it wasn't accepting the hashes I was giving it.  I generated a pwd using your python script and it worked like a charm.  As for moving forward, this information is really handy for future projects that deal with encryption, many thanks!