# PureFTPD 1.0.50 with MariaDB fails to auth, possible reason wrong hash

Tags: hash, pureftpd

I am using pure-ftpd with MariaDB to auth users. After upgrade to Debian 12 Bookworm it stopped working. Debian 12 includes new [pure-ftpd 1.0.50](https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/news/#version-1050-released), which has introduced the following change:

```
Support for MD5, SHA1 and the MySQL PASSWORD() function were removed for password hashing. You should now use scrypt, argon2 or the system crypt(3) function.
```

So I updated /etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf to reflect the changes (before I used md5):

```
# Mandatory : how passwords are stored
# Valid values are : "cleartext", "argon2", "scrypt", "crypt", and "any"
MYSQLCrypt      crypt
```

I tried to generate hash with the following [one-liner](https://serverfault.com/questions/837744/pure-ftpd-with-mysql-crypt-not-logging-me-in-with-hashed-passwords):

```
python3 -c 'import sys, crypt, getpass; print(crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass("Password: "), crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'
```

For example, for password "test" I get "$6$98sU0xdVjMC7CQk0$f5548Rnp4FBkF0lxHfU3P1Jpa0Y0ZtWg7BvNoeA91/U05gPnVi3yf1XRBuedwcYRk5YnFRdhn6/bZQm0xsKkW0". I put the result of this function to the database, but it still tells me "Login authentication failed":

```
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
331 User xxx OK. Password required
Password: 
530 Login authentication failed
ftp: Login failed
ftp> exit
```

I tried to turn on verbose output, but no more information is provided.
Has anyone managed to get working pure-ftpd 1.0.50 with MariaDB/MySQL?
When I try `MYSQLCrypt      cleartext`, than it works fine, but I don't consider it as a best option to store passwords in cleartext.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem yesterday when upgraded from ubuntu server 20.04 to 22.04.
Changed md5 to crypt as advised in accepted answer here:

[Pure-ftpd with MySQL - Crypt() not logging me in with hashed passwords](https://serverfault.com/questions/837744/pure-ftpd-with-mysql-crypt-not-logging-me-in-with-hashed-passwords?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also had to recover user passwords, as some MD5 were not easy to decrypt with this command:

```
sudo tcpdump -l -i enp2s0 -f "port 21" | grep -i PASS --line-buffered > recoveredFTPpasswords.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I use argon2

If you are porting from another version, you need to change the table using

```
ALTER TABLE `ftpd` CHANGE `Password` `Password` VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL;
```

Install argon2

```
$ apt install argon2
```

And you can use a simple script to make your password in argon2

```
$ cat > /usr/local/bin/pw-pure-argon2

#!/bin/bash
salt=$(echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20)
echo -n "Password: "
read -s password
arg=$(echo -n $password | argon2 $salt | grep Encoded | awk '{ print $2}')
echo -e "$arg\n"
```

Change privs

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pw-pure-argon2
```

Execute, insert the new password

```
$ pw-pure-argon2

Password: $argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$Y2YwY2JlZTdjZjNiMzVkZjJkMjY$lXbtcmoPkXH3gAchwVkkUZjOi4Vm7oFj7GzbUKRWaG0
```

Insert into mysql table and that's all.